# Can simultaneous, expensive CSS transitions be in phase?

Tags: css, css-transitions

There have been questions about [the absolute timing precision of CSS transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715088/do-css-animations-work-on-strict-time-basis) and about [removing jitter for inexpensive simultaneous transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16532809/cleaning-up-css-jitters). However, the answers didn't give me a clear idea of the *relative* accuracy of the animation timings (e.g. if two simultaneous animations are "in-phase"), especially when the transitions get expensive.

The effect is most obvious when working with images, like in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yLag8yq/1/), where the image and container are moving in opposite directions simultaneously trying to keep the image in the same absolute position, but the asynchrony is causing jitter:

```
/* CSS */
#container {
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  left:200px;
  overflow:hidden;
  background-position:-200px -150px;

  -webkit-backface-visiblity:hidden;
  -webkit-transition:all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition:all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition:all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition:all 2s ease-in-out;
}

/* JS */
$(function() {
  $('#container').css('left', 0).css('background-position', '0 -150px');
});
```

Curiously, the jitter is consistently to the right of neutral, which means that the image animation phases are a tad ahead of the container's. It's kind of hard to see, but comparing the offset frames to the stationary final frame, the direction bias is visible.

[image]

Is there any way to make sure each step of both transitions are rendered simultaneously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are seeing is referred to as **[*Jank*](http://jankfree.org/)**.

It happens because of the CSS properties you are trying to animate. Both of these 2 CSS properties i.e. `left` & `background-position` trigger *paint* & *compositing* operations. Additionally, `left` property triggers *layout* as well.

Have a read on the subject of **[High Performance Animations](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/)** and also take a look at which CSS properties trigger which operation over at **[CSS Triggers](http://csstriggers.com/)**.

As a solution, you might want to **[animate `translateX` instead of `left`](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)** property. The result will be a little better but we would still have `background-position` to deal with which would keep triggering the heavy operation of re-painting.

I think the best solution, in my humble opinion and I could be completely wrong in approaching it, is to have an `img` tag inside your `#container` element, provide the image as its `src` and remove all the `background` related properties from your CSS.

And then move it as well using the same `translate` mentioned above. This way, hopefully, you will get the smoothest of results.

Take a look at **[this updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/m5xeq5m3/2/)** or the snippet below.

***Snippet:***

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#container').css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(0)',
    '-moz-transform': 'translateX(0)',
    '-o-transform': 'translateX(0)',
    'transform': 'translateX(0)'
  });
  $('#container > img').css({
    '-webkit-transform': 'translate(0px, -150px)',
    '-moz-transform': 'translate(0px, -150px)',
    '-o-transform': 'translate(0px, -150px)',
    'transform': 'translate(0px, -150px)'
  });
});
```

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(200px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(200px);
  -o-transform: translateX(200px);
  transform: translateX(200px);
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
#container > img {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-200px, -150px);
  -moz-transform: translate(-200px, -150px);
  -o-transform: translate(-200px, -150px);
  transform: translate(-200px, -150px);
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="container">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1448975750337-b0290d621d6d?crop=entropy&dpr=2&fit=crop&fm=jpg&h=775&ixjsv=2.1.0&ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=50&w=1450" />
</span>
```

P.S. As a side note, I am a big fan of **[GSAP](http://greensock.com/gsap)** (a JavaScript animation suite of tools). Here is **[another example](https://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/m5xeq5m3/3/)** using `TweenMax` (one of the tools from GSAP) which animates `x` property (a shorthand for `translateX` within the GSAP world and which also takes care of all the browser prefixes for you behind the scenes) in a more intuitive way using **[`.fromTo()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TweenMax/fromTo/)** method.